# Array.map2 type inference on records

Tags: f#

I ran into something with Array.map2 that I don't understand.

Consider this code:

```
type r1 = {
    v1 : int
    X : int
}

type r2 = {
    v1 : int 
    Y : int
}

let a1 = [|{v1=1;   X=1};   {v1=2;   X=2}|]   // val a1 : r1 [] ...
let a2 = [|{v1=100; Y=100}; {v1=200; Y=200}|] // val a2 : r2 [] ...

Array.map2 (fun x1 x2 -> (x1.X, x2.Y)) a1 a2   // works as expected
Array.map2 (fun x1 x2 -> (x1.v1, x2.v1)) a1 a2  // error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a r2 [] but given a r1 []
```

Both records have a field `v1`. In the last line, I try to get a tuple of the values of `v1`, but from the different record types `r1` and `r2`. It seems to throw an error when I try to select fields that have the same name on different records.

Somehow it jumps to the conclusion that `x1` must be of type `r2`, why doesn't the second line infer the type from the two parameters `a1` and `a2`?

*edit*

This fixes it but I would expect to get the type right from the parameters.

```
Array.map2 (fun (x1:r1) x2 -> (x1.v1, x2.v1)) a1 a2  // works
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type checker works from left to right, so there isn't enough information to resolve conflicts in the second example. Your first example is fine because `.X` and `.Y` are unique fields on `r1` and `r2` respectively.

That said, in this case you could use piping to make types of `a1` and `a2` available to the type checker prior accessing record fields:

```
(a1, a2) ||> Array.map2 (fun x1 x2 -> (x1.v1, x2.v1))
```

In general, you should use [record patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx) which contain unique fields to identify correct types:

```
Array.map2 (fun {v1 = a; X = _} {v1 = b; Y = _} -> (a, b)) a1 a2
```

or provide fully qualified field names:

```
Array.map2 (fun {r1.v1 = a} {r2.v1 = b} -> (a, b)) a1 a2
```